# x^2+y^2=2, xy=1, how to find x and y

Tags: elementary-set-theory, systems-of-equations

I have problems when doing these equations when I don't know any variable's value.
Can someone please explain how to do this and possibly give some tips when it comes to solving these problems?

Well, I know x = 1 and y = 1, but what about this one:
a-b=3, a:b=3:2, find a^2-b^2
(I am not quite is a:b=3:2 = a/b:3/2 or it was meant to be that way)

Comment: In general, you could try:  substitute, solve the quartic, check the solutions work

Comment: Um... I have to ask what classes have you had and why you did not learn how to do this in the classes?  These are simple substitution.  You express one variable in term of the other ($y =\frac 1x$ or $a = \frac 32 b$) and plug it into the other to get an expression with one variable ($x^2 + \frac 1{x^2}=2$ or ($a-b=\frac 32 b-b=3$) and solve for that variable ($x=\pm 1$ or $b=6$) and plug that back in to get the other ($y=\frac 1x=\frac 1{\pm 1}=\pm 1$ or $a =\frac 32b=\frac 32*6=9$.)  If that's not clear I don't know what to do to help you.

Comment: I hate the notation $a:b$ but it's a ratio.  $a:b =3:2$ $a$ is proportional to $b$ as $3$ is proportional to $2$ which means $\frac ab = \frac 32$.  It can also be interpreted as $\frac a3=\frac b2$ which are equivalent statements.  $\frac ab =\frac 32 \iff 2a=3b;b\ne 0;2\ne 0 \iff \frac a3 = \frac b2;3\ne 0; 2\ne 0;b\ne 0$.

Comment: Actually instead of using $a:b = 3:2$ to get $a =\frac 32 b$ it'd have been a lot easier to use $a-b = 3$ so $a = 3+b$ so $\frac a{b}=\frac {3+b}{b}= \frac 32$ so $2(3+b) = 3b$ so $6+2b = 3b$ and $b = 6$ so $a=3+b = 3+6 = 9$.

Comment: I had an appendix surgery so I was not in the school :/

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $(x+y)^2 = x^2+y^2+2xy$ and $(x-y)^2 = x^2 + y^2 - 2 xy.$ So $(x+y)^2 = 4$ and $(x-y)^2 = 0.$ Therefore $x+y= \pm 2$ and $x - y = 0.$ So either $x=y=1$ or $x=y=-1.$

Answer (score 1):

Since $xy=1$ it is $x^2+y^2=2xy$, which gives us $x^2-2xy+y^2=0\Leftrightarrow (x-y)^2=0$

This means, it has to be $x=y$. From the condition $xy=1$ we deduce $x^2=1\Leftrightarrow x=y=\pm 1$, which gives the only two solution $(1,1), (-1,-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2+y^2=2$ and $xy=1$, then$$(x-y)^2=x^2+y^2-2xy=2-2=0.$$Therefore, $x=y$. But now the second equation becomes $x^2=1$. So, the only solutions are $x=y=1$ and $x=y=-1$.

Answer (score 0):

First you can see that $x \ne 0 $ (otherwise $xy = 0$). So we get to $y = \frac{1}{x}$ and then substitute: $x^2 + \frac{1}{x^2} = 1$ and then $x^4 + 1 = 2x^2$ which lead to $$x^4 - 2x^2 + 1 = 0$$ whcih means $(x^2-1)^2 = 0$

so $x^2 = 1$ and we get $x = y =  1 \text{ or } x= y=-1$